# sending data from template to flask

Tags: javascript, python, sql, flask

I'm making a website using flask.
It displays a list using sql in top.html in which each element is a hypertext.

```
 <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead></thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
  </tr></thead>
  <tbody>
        {% for company in companies %}
            <tr>
                <td><a href="{{ url_for('text') }}" method = "POST" name = "{{ company.name }}">{{ company.name }}</a></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
</table>
```

So i want to know which hypertext is clicked from the list so that i could load its respective content in /text.
please provide the python code also(flask code).

Answer (score 0):

First put company unique identifier to each <a for example <a data-id="11" ...

Then add event listeners on each <a like this...

```js
var companyLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.table-striped a');

for (var i = 0; i < companyLinks.length; i += 1) {
    companyLinks[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        // get the company id of clicked link
        var companyId = e.target.dataset.id;

        // now do what you like with the company id
        // for example you can send an AJAX call to your backend
    });
}
```

Comment: should i include event listeners inside the companies for loop or outside?

Comment: also please write the backend code in python flask to access companyId there.

Comment: ad 1. Put the provided snippet inside <script type="text/javascript"></script> outside the loop after </table>.
ad 2. I have no idea what REST resources you are exposing but as I wrote above if you have clicked company and you got company id you can for example make AJAX call like this:  $.get( "/details/" + companyId ); // <-- this will work if you use jQuery library. In pure JS you can use XMLHttpRequest object. Hope this will help.